# Update multiple grade at once

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to change the grade of each student in the instructor list.
I don't know what is wrong here. 
Please can you help me.
This is the code of sub-doc.php

this is savesub_doc.php

```
 <?php
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

       foreach($_POST['sh_grade'] as $gr){

           $i =$_POST['sh_id'];
           $sqiil="UPDATE grade SET sh_grade[]='$gr' WHERE sh_id='$i' ";

                  if(mysqli_query($conn,$sqiil)){
                              }                                   

            }}
 ?>
```

sub_doc.php

```
 <input type="hidden" name="sh_id[]" value="<?php echo $row["sh_id"]; ?>" >            

 <input type="text" name="sh_grade[]" value='<?php echo $row['sh_grade'];?>">
 <input type="submit"  value="Submit" name="submit">
```

Comment: `$sqiil="UPDATE grade SET sh_grade[]='".$gr."' WHERE sh_id='".$i."' ";`

Comment: Thank you for your comment Mr.Jonathan. When I putted your suggestion it was Notice: Array to string conversion error. How can I solve it ?

Comment: I solve it by changing  <input type="hidden" name="sh_id" value="<?php echo $row["sh_id"]; ?>" > but now there is no changes in the db

Comment: Can you describe your grade table?

Comment: my grade table contains sh_id PK, postername (the student name), posterid and his grade sh_grade. I want to change the grade of students

Comment: What is `sh_grade[]` supposed to be? Do you really have brackets in the name of the column in the database?

Comment: I'm using sh_grade is the db not sh_grade[ ] , I'm using sh_grade[ ] to make many changes in the same times. Please let me know if there is something wrong

Comment: I understand why you use `sh_grade[]` in the HTML, but you shouldn't use it in the SQL. SQL doesn't have arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a parametrized query to prevent SQL injection. And I doubt that the name of the table column has `[]` in it.

You also need to index `$_POST['sh_id']` to get the corresponding ID for each grade.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE grade SET sh_grade = ? WHERE sh_id = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $gr, $id);
    foreach ($_POST['sh_grade'] as $i => $gr) {
        $id = $_POST['sh_id'][$i];
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean I need to put this code in my form `<input type="hidden" name="sh_id[]" value="<?php echo $row["sh_id"]; ?>" >            

 <input type="text" name="sh_grade[]" value='<?php echo $row['sh_grade'];?>">
 <input type="submit"  value="Submit" name="submit"> `. or something else ?

Comment: There's no change to the form. This just replaces the loop you have to do the updates.

Comment: It's WOORRK !! Thank you very muccch !!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
   foreach($_POST["sh_grade"] as $keys => $gr){
     $i = $_POST["sh_id"][$keys];
     $sqiil="UPDATE grade SET sh_grade = " . $_POST["sh_grade"][$keys] . "WHERE sh_id = " . $i;
     if(mysqli_query($conn,$sqiil)){                              }                                   

     }}
?>
```

Try this and let me know if you will have issue!!

Comment: I need to change something else in the form ? Because when I put it it was Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) error

Comment: I have updated code. Please check and make sure that your field will be same as you have mentioned above..

Comment: I change it into `$sqiil="UPDATE sub_doc SET sh_grade = '".$_POST['sh_grade'][$keys]."' WHERE sh_id='".$i."";` . I solved error problem, but it still there is no changes in the db. Maybe I need to change something else in the form

Comment: I'm written `<input type="hidden" name="sh_id[]" value="<?php echo $row["sh_id"]; ?>" >            

 <input type="text" name="sh_grade[]" value='<?php echo $row['sh_grade'];?>">
 <input type="submit"  value="Submit" name="submit"> ` in my form, is it correct ?

Comment: Yes. You are creating array of sh_id and sh_grade using input.

Comment: but it still there is no changes in the db. do you think I need to do something else ?

Comment: May i know your tables and their element name ?

Comment: my grade table contains sh_id as a PK, postername (the student name), posterid (student id) and his grade sh_grade

Comment: you need to do var_dump($sqiil) and get a string from your web browser to paste it on SQL query of your table. If query will be executed that mean your SQL query will work on PHP file (Cross verification)